# Best practices to follow/read large mailing-lists?

Tags: mailing-list, mailing

You're probably a lot to be subscribers to various mailing list, some more updated than others.

- What are your best practices to follow all information going by these lists?
- What are the best clients you've used to managed that?

I'm sure I'm not the only one trying to get the best signal out of this noisy way of communication :)

Comment: http://www.gweep.ca/~edmonds/usenet/ml-etiquette.html

Comment: @Robhruska The link is dead, but probably helpful, can you update it, please?!

Comment: Here's an archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170426175120/www.gweep.ca/~edmonds/usenet/ml-etiquette.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like gmail because of the way it groups messages by conversation so I can just page down through a thread.

Answer (score 4):

Use a rule in GMail to slap a label on and archive all of them.  Then they are easily sortable, searchable, and threaded.

Answer (score 3):

I just use Thunderbird. For some lists, in flat mode, for others (the Lua mailing list), in threaded mode. Following is natural for mailing list, the messages are pushed to your client.

At first, I just received the messages and routed them to the right folder with some rules.

Now, I read them as newsgroups using [Gmane](http://gmane.org/), which also allow to catch up history (including mails which were sent before my subscription started and those which were sent during a temporary unsubscription).

Sometime, when a thread has no interest for me, I just right click on the first message and select Mark all messages of this thread as read.

Comment: As said, messages are neatly / automatically threaded in their own newsgroup section, and you can use a newsgroup client instead, if you find it more convenient. And as said, it allows to access history, not to be limited to the messages emitted after your subscription. Note that with this method, you have to tell the ML not to send you messages... Still have to subscribe to be allowed to post, of course.

Comment: I didn't think about that, although it's pretty trivial. I suggested an edit which doesn't hurt imo. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Using KDE Ia m using Kontact for my mail and RSS feeds. That gives me a nice command center.

Comment: That doesn't explain how to follow large mailing lists since this setup seems essentially identical to what other setups provide.